# gryo scope and accelerometer output

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, accelerometer, gyroscope

I am currently working on project using and arduino, a gyro, an accelerometer, and a Bluetooth chip to try to model some data. I am currently trying to gather data, package it up and send it to a phone via Bluetooth. The issue is the Bluetooth chip I am using is a low energy one and so it can only send messages of 20 bytes at a time. I am trying to get past this issue by storing the data collected for a certain amount of time then send it all in 20 byte bursts. I am currently testing this method without sending the data and just printing the data to the serial monitor. This is where my issue is arising, when printing the data in real time everything works but when I try to store it in an array I get this:

593,575,567,0,0,0

592,575,567,0,0,0

592,575,567,0,0,0

592,575,567,0,0,0

592,575,567,0,0,0

593,575,567,0,0,0

586,576,568,0,0,0

0,0,0

0,0

0,0

,0,0,0

0,0,0

As you can see it seems to just break. If anyone could help me out it would be great!

Here is the relevant code chunk

```
for(int i = 0; i < loopVal; i++)
  {
    yawGyroValDouble = 0;
    pitchGyroValDouble = 0;
    rollGyroValDouble = 0;
    totalClicksY = 0;
    angleY = 0;
    totalClicksP = 0;
    angleP = 0;
    totalClicksR = 0;
    angleR = 0;      
    xRe = 0;
    yRe = 0;
    zRe = 0;
    s = "";
    int starttime = millis(); // get start time
    int endtime = starttime; // init end time
    while ((endtime - starttime) < time)
    {
      getGyroValues();  // This will update rollGyroVal, pitchGyroVal, and yawGyroVal with new values

      yawGyroValDouble =yawGyroVal;
      if(abs(yawGyroValDouble) > abs(gyroNoiseThresh)){ // ignore noise
        totalClicksY+=yawGyroValDouble; // update runsum
      }

      pitchGyroValDouble =pitchGyroVal;
      if(abs(yawGyroValDouble) > abs(gyroNoiseThresh)){ // ignore noise
        totalClicksP+=pitchGyroValDouble; // update runsum
      }

      rollGyroValDouble =rollGyroVal;
      if(abs(yawGyroValDouble) > abs(gyroNoiseThresh)){ // ignore noise
        totalClicksR+=rollGyroValDouble; // update runsum
      }

      xRe = analogRead(pinX);

      yRe = analogRead(pinY);

      zRe = analogRead(pinZ);

      delay (gyroDelayTime);
      endtime = millis();
    }

    angleY = totalClicksY / clicksPerDegCCW;
    angleP = totalClicksP / clicksPerDegCCW;
    angleR = totalClicksR / clicksPerDegCCW;

    String yawSend = String(angleY);

    String pitchSend = String(angleP);

    String rollSend = String(angleR);

    String xSend = String(xRe);

    String ySend = String(yRe);

    String zSend = String(zRe);


    //s = "Accel - X: " + xSend + " Y: " + ySend + " Z: " + zSend + "\n" + "Gyro - Yaw: " + yawSend + " Pitch: " + pitchSend + " Roll: " + rollSend;
    s = "" + xSend + "," + ySend + "," + zSend + "," + yawSend + "," + pitchSend + "," + rollSend;
    Serial.println(s);
    res[i] = s;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show where `totalClicksY`, `totalClicksP`, `totalClicksR`, and  `clicksPerDegCCW` are declared, but I'm betting they are declared as integer types (int or long).  If so, the result of your maths:

```
angleY = totalClicksY / clicksPerDegCCW;
angleP = totalClicksP / clicksPerDegCCW;
angleR = totalClicksR / clicksPerDegCCW;
```

will be integers.  And if the results of those divisions are less than 1, they will be truncated to 0.

Try declaring `totalClicksY`, `totalClicksP`, `totalClicksR` and `clicksPerDegCCW` as `double`.  That, or cast them when you do the math, like this:

```
angleY = (double)totalClicksY / (double)clicksPerDegCCW;
angleP = (double)totalClicksP / (double)clicksPerDegCCW;
angleR = (double)totalClicksR / (double)clicksPerDegCCW;
```

(I'm also assuming that `angleY`, `angleP`, and `angleR` are also declared as doubles - if not they definitely should be).

Comment: These are already set to be doubles. I found out the problem after some testing. It turns out I am running out of RAM. The only solution to which is to buy more RAM! Thanks though!